# log4net configuration for each project C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, log4net

I have 3 Class Lib projects as (ClassLib1.dll, ClassLib2.dll, ClassLib3.dll).
One Windows service project. WindowsService1.

Log for net is configure for Windows Service project and log4net is in config file as

```
    <log4net> 
    <root>
      <level value="all" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <file value="C:\\XX\\Logs\\{App_Name}\\{App_Name_Log_File_}" />
      <countDirection value="1" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%utcdate{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff} %-level [%thread] [%M %C] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

Windows service is referring calling 3 Class Lib projects.
How can I configure log4 net for these 3 class lib so that I can have a log file in the separate folder as below?

For Main windows service 
C:\XX\Logs\Win_Servive\Win_Service_Log_File_.log
For Class Lib 1
C:\XX\Logs\ClassLib1\ClassLib1_Log_File_.log
For Class Lib 2
C:\XX\Logs\ClassLib2\ClassLib2_Log_File_.log
For Class Lib 3
C:\XX\Logs\ClassLib3\ClassLib3_Log_File_.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by configuring three different appenders on the web.config file, then loading three different loggers by name:

```
 <appender name="Class1Appender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" additivity="false">....</appender>
 <appender name="Class2Appender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" additivity="false">....</appender>
 <appender name="Class3Appender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" additivity="false">....</appender>
```

Then use the appropriate logger:

```
ILog class1Log = LogManager.GetLogger("Class1Appender");
ILog class2Log = LogManager.GetLogger("Class2Appender");
ILog class3Log = LogManager.GetLogger("Class3Appender");
```

Comment: Thank you Juan, Now separate folders are created but the log statement in each log file is same.

Comment: That's just configuration. Change the <file /> node attributes on each one so that the file name is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Final log4net config as below

```
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="all" />
</root>

<logger name="WinService">
  <appender-ref ref="WinService" />
</logger>

<logger name="ClassLibrary1">
  <appender-ref ref="ClassLib1" />
</logger>

<logger name="ClassLibrary2">
  <appender-ref ref="ClassLib2" />
</logger>

<logger name="ClassLibrary3">
  <appender-ref ref="ClassLib3" />
</logger>

<appender name="WinService" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" additivity="false">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <file value="C:\\XX\\Logs\\WinService\\WinService_" />
  <countDirection value="1" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%utcdate{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff} %-level [%thread] [%M %C] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="ClassLib1" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" additivity="false">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <file value="C:\\XX\\Logs\\ClassLib1\\ClassLib1_" />
  <countDirection value="1" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%utcdate{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff} %-level [%thread] [%M %C] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="ClassLib2" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" additivity="false">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <file value="C:\\XX\\Logs\\ClassLib2\\ClassLib2_" />
  <countDirection value="1" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%utcdate{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff} %-level [%thread] [%M %C] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="ClassLib3" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" additivity="false">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <file value="C:\\XX\\Logs\\ClassLib3\\ClassLib3_" />
  <countDirection value="1" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%utcdate{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff} %-level [%thread] [%M %C] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```